# How can I make fatal errors of ALL mysql warnings?

Tags: mysql, warnings

Is there any way to promote all mysql warnings to fatal errors? I'd like to avoid any data truncation (including fractional parts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some modes, MySQL raises warnings instead of the errors that are required by the SQL Standard.

You certainly want to raise an error when significant data is removed, but you probably don't want an error raised when a COUNT(colname) expression finds some rows with nulls in the column and ignores them for counting purposes (a Standard warning).

As MySQL becomes more conformant to the Standard, warnings that do not have data integrity implications may be added.

If using MySQL in a mode that more closely follows the SQL Standard is not enough, you could catch the unacceptable warnings in your application code and add appropriate compensating actions.

Answer (score 6):

I'm can't say whether this will promote *all* warnings to errors so apologies if you're already aware of this, but there are several [MySQL server modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html) that might work for you:

> TRADITIONAL
>
> Make MySQL behave like a “traditional” SQL database system. A simple description of this mode is “give an error instead of a warning” when inserting an incorrect value into a column.

[`STRICT_ALL_TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables) is part of `TRADITIONAL`:

> Strict mode controls how MySQL handles input values that are invalid or missing. A value can be invalid for several reasons. For example, it might have the wrong data type for the column, or it might be out of range

Comment: This doesn't work. Many warnings are still warnings even after setting `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`.