# Error: Update Varchar values to Datetime in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date-formatting

DB DETAIL Table name(KK)-

```
id      name         date(varchar(50))                         

1       Ayush        2020-04-19T18:56:09.774Z
```

I am using this query to convert -

```
update KK set date=DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE( KK.date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s' ), '%Y-%m-%d %T') where id=1;
```

Getting this error

> Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2020-04-19T18:56:09.774Z'

Comment: That should be a warning in MySQL. Do you have [MySQL in traditional or strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289205/how-can-i-make-fatal-errors-of-all-mysql-warnings)?

Answer (score 1):

Your current date string has `.774Z` following the seconds, but your STR_TO_DATE() format string doesn't account for it. So it's warning you that there are extra characters at the end of the string that weren't parsed.

If you use `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ'` the warning stops.

Answer (score 1):

The times have two parts your format is missing: milliseconds, the `.774` part, and the "zulu" time zone `Z`.

```
select STR_TO_DATE('2020-04-19T18:56:09.774Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ');
```

However, since you're truncating them anyway, I'd use the less restrictive format and just ignore the warning.

---

Since the string is already in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), you can skip the `str_to_date`.

```
mysql> select DATE_FORMAT('2020-04-19T18:56:09.774Z', '%Y-%m-%d %T');
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT('2020-04-19T18:56:09.774Z', '%Y-%m-%d %T') |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 2020-04-19 18:56:09                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

The MySQL warning is because it doesn't seem to understand that Z is a valid [time zone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators).

Note that this *will* account for a time zone. This may or may not be what you want.

```
-- date_format will display in the current time zone.
-- I'm in -07:00, so a +00:00 (UTC) date is displayed -7 hours.
mysql> select DATE_FORMAT('2020-04-19T18:56:09.777+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T');
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT('2020-04-19T18:56:09.777+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2020-04-19 11:56:09                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

And, finally, consider altering that column to be a [`datetime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) type. Then everything is stored in UTC and these conversion problems go away.

Comment: When I am using DATE_FORMAT directly then it is giving the same eror.