# Mysql event schedule with if statement,

Tags: mysql

I need to decrease all values in an integer column. When one of them equals to 0, it should stop to decrease that value and continue to decrease all other values in that column.
I do this with event schedule in Mysql. This works:

```
UPDATE dbname.tablename SET money = money - 1;
```

But if I add if statement, it does not works

```
IF dbname.tablename.money > 0 THEN
UPDATE dbname.tablename SET money = money - 1;
END IF
```

Comment: `UPDATE dbname.tablename SET money = money - 1 WHERE money>0;`

Comment: I think this link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456258/mysql-truncated-incorrect-double-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to limit the execution to rows containing a value in `money` greater than zero

```
UPDATE dbname.tablename SET money = money - 1 WHERE money>0;
```