# 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So, i'm trying to update multiple lines with a prepared statement in PDO:

```
UPDATE uploads SET stored_until=:stored_until WHERE name IN (FIND_IN_SET(uploads.name, :name_list))
```

And i'm getting an axception

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '5320f3c10eb41fe3ceaf65c3b457538e.txt'
```

I understood, that somehow some "name" from Array is counting as a Date, but i can't understand why

Colums, that used in code:

```
`name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
`stored_until` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Here's the part, where query executes

```
$name_list = $json['files'];
$date = new DateTime($_GET['date']);
$date->modify("+2 weeks");
$query->execute(array("stored_until" => $date->format("Y-m-d"), "name_list" => $name_list));
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to insert the name in to the date field. Perhaps you have your parameters `:stored_until` and `:name_list` mixed up in your PHP. Show us the code where you construct the query.

Comment: Your `stored_until` column is defined as a DATE, and you try to pass it a filename.  Look at how you assign your variables to the update statement.  Add your code here, without it, we do not have much to go on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456258/mysql-truncated-incorrect-double-value)