# "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value" error in DataHandler TYPO3 9

Tags: typo3-9.x, datahandler

I have an array with about 400 records to insert into a database table

I have tried inserting with the DataHandler and I faced the issues below:

- After inserting 195 records, it gives the "**Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value**" error.
  When try creating new record in the list module, it still gives the error above.
- If I limit the records to insert to a maximum of 194, records are inserted with no errors
  and I can also create records in the list module but the records are duplicated in the database.

For another approach, I used the QueryBuilder's insert() to directly insert the data into the database table.

- All the data was inserted as I wanted but when I try to create a new record in the List module, I get the "**Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value**" again.
- But if I limit to 194 no error occurs in the List module when creating a new record.

I will be very glad on help with this problem.

Comment: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/Ctrl/Index.html#sortby 
I had this problem and this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

I found something regarding that error and MySQL, e.g. [MYSQL Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456258/mysql-truncated-incorrect-double-value)

It seems to come from obscure syntax and other quite unrelated MySQL parser errors.

I would try changing values from int to string in your DataHandler-array.

To help you one would need the relevant Datahandler-code with the array-record that is failing and the column definition (`DESCRIBE tablename`) for the table in question. Also the database version would be interesting.