# mysql replication error: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql, master-slave

I use mysql master-slave replication for backing-up database, but the slave server got the following error after several days:

```
Last_SQL_Errno: 1292
Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '29''' on query. Default database: 'my_database'. Query: 'UPDATE `a_table`  SET `name`='xxx',`phone`='xxx',`mch_key`='xxx',`switch`='1',`update_time`=1592612052  WHERE  `id` = '29\'''
```

It seems that the "column id value 29" is not correct by trailing with two single quote symbol. But I don't know how was this happened.
How can I debug this problem?

mysql version: master and slave is same version 5.7.30.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value' is a misleading error message in MySQL. I have encountered this issue and this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456258/mysql-truncated-incorrect-double-value) post helped me to resolve my issue.

In my case, although the value in the where clause looked like a number, it was a string and introducing quotes to the value in the where clause solved the issue since it was actually "varchar".

I hope the content on the SO post linked above (answers *and comments by different users*) will help to find the cause of your issue! Good luck!